# How to update headers in $resource when routing to a new state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, jwt, angular-services, angular-local-storage

I'm trying to implement JWT token in this project. For that I used Authorization header in the `$resource`, like as this.

When I login on UI state "A", after getting logged in, I put the token in the localStorage as

```
$localStorage.token = data.token;
```

**When I go to UI state "B" of the page, it uses the following service and send a request with no token. But on refreshing the page, it sends the same request with the token.**

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin')
    .factory('valueService', ['Token','$localStorage','$resource', 'endpoint', function(Token,$localStorage, $resource, endpoint) {
        return {
            getValues: $resource(endpoint + '/admin/getvalues', null, {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer '+$localStorage.token}
                 }
            }),
        }   
}]);
```

I think the service stores the `$localStorage.token` value initially and uses that even when the state changes. But when the page is reloaded, it gets the `$localStorage.token` value again.

How do I force this service to get the `$localStorage.token` value everytime the UI state changes?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: It was working with the get request, but when I was sending post request, i got the error that its not a constructor. And the one solution that i marked as correct now requires less effort as I do not need to do changes in my controllers, instead just change one line in the service. Hope you understand. Yours was correct too and so I upvoted it too :)

Comment: Well, changing the code into `method: 'POST'` works very well here. The solution is independent on the `HTTP-Method` you use. Both solutions (the other answer) does work very fine. I understand that the other solution is more equal of what you have tried before. Keep in mind, that the other solution will only work for set headers. For example `method: $localStorage.method` will not work. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have the resource compute the header value on each XHR GET operation, furnish a function instead of a value:

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin')
    .factory('valueService', ['Token','$localStorage','$resource', 'endpoint', function(Token,$localStorage, $resource, endpoint) {
        return {
            getValues: $resource(endpoint + '/admin/getvalues', null, {
                'get': {
                    method: 'GET',
                    //headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer '+$localStorage.token}
                    headers:
                       {'Authorization':
                            function () {
                               return 'Bearer '+$localStorage.token;
                            }
                       }
                 }
            }),
        }   
}]);
```

When a value is furnished, the header value is computed when the resource is created. When a function is furnished, the header value is computed each time the resource `get` method is called.

> - headers – `{Object}` – Map of strings **or functions which return strings** representing HTTP headers to send to the server. If the return value of a function is null, the header will not be sent. Functions accept a config object as an argument.
>
>   [-- AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Usage](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the resource definition is provided at the time of creation (before you have saved a token). To avoid this behavior, simply create a wrapper function and parse your token into it.

```
angular.module('BlurAdmin')
    .factory('valueService', ['Token','$localStorage','$resource', 'endpoint', function(Token,$localStorage, $resource, endpoint) {
        return function (token) {
            return $resource(endpoint + '/admin/getvalues', {}, {
                get: {
                    method: 'GET',
                    headers:{'Authorization':'Bearer ' + token}
                }
            })
        }
    }]);
```

Call your factory function like:

```
valueService($localStorage.token).get(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
}, function (error) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: HI lin, Initially I was calling it like  var getValues = new valueService().getValues();

              getValues.$get({},function(data){
                  console.log(data);
                  if (data.status == "success") {

                   $scope.values = data.response;
                  } else {
                   $scope.notify = {
                      message: data.statusMessage,
                      status: data.status,
                      type: "danger"
                    }
                  }
              });

Comment: What change should I do to this now?

Comment: Add the wrapper function you see in `line 3` and parse `$localStorage.token` into it like `valueService($localStorage.token).getValues)...`

Comment: Yeah I did that. But how do I call the service's $get function now?

Comment: var getValues = new valueService($localStorage.token).getValues();
            getValues.$get({},function(data){
                console.log(data);
            })

Comment: I tried this but got the error of "cannot read property $get of undefined"

Comment: @AbhishekKulshrestha I updated your factory with a more simple structure. I also updated the factory call. Take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the header with many API calls, It is better to add it in a commom place rather than adding it with each API

Please refer : intercepter https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

```
angular.module('utimf.services', ['ngResource', 'ng.deviceDetector'])
.factory('UtimfHttpIntercepter', UtimfHttpIntercepter)

UtimfHttpIntercepter.$inject = ['$q', '$localStorage'];
function UtimfHttpIntercepter($q, $localStorage) {
var authFactory = {};

var _request = function (config) {
    config.headers = config.headers || {}; // change/add hearders
    config.data = config.data || {}; // change/add post data
    config.params = config.params || {}; //change/add querystring params
    config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+$localStorage.token; // New headers are added here          

    return config || $q.when(config);
}

var _requestError = function (rejection) {
    // handle if there is a request error
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}

var _response = function(response){
    // handle your response
    return response || $q.when(response);
}

var _responseError = function (rejection) {
    // handle if there is a request error
    return $q.reject(rejection);
}

authFactory.request = _request;
authFactory.requestError = _requestError;
authFactory.response = _response;
authFactory.responseError = _responseError;
return authFactory;
}
```

and add `$httpProvider.interceptors.push('UtimfHttpIntercepter');` in your config

Comment: How does this solve the users problem?  This is a "how to refactoring" answer.